# What did Harry mean when he thought that Sirius would have greeted him with a laugh like a bark?

Tags: harry-potter, sirius-black, order-of-the-phoenix

Here is the paragraph from the book:

*Sirius seemed a million miles away already; even now a part of Harry still believed that if he had only pulled back that veil, he would have found Sirius looking back at him, greeting him, perhaps, with his laugh like a bark ...*

Comment: Sirius is known as the Dog Star, that's all I know

Comment: @barrycarter I think that's enough. You could provide a cite for Sirius being the Greek name for the Dog Star and make an answer.

Comment: @user888379 feel free to turn my comment into an answer, I'm too lazy :)

Comment: Sirius also initially appears in the series disguised as a large black dog.

Comment: I don't think we need to know anything about the Dog Star. Simply, Harry remembers Sirius's laugh as sounding like a bark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Sirius' animagus form is a dog, he's often described as being a bit dog-like at times, so I'm guessing his laughter description is more of that. However, "barking laughter" or "a bark of laughter" is a phrase in English that describes a laugh that is loud and sudden. See definition 1.1 at [this link](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bark).

Answer (score 0):

Sirius’s laugh is described as bark-like on several prior occasions:

> Sirius let out a laugh that was much more like a bark.
>
> <sup>(*Goblet of Fire*, Chapter Twenty-Seven)</sup>

> Sirius gave a short, barklike laugh. “If my parents could see the use it was being put to now... well, my mother’s portrait should give you some idea...”
>
> <sup>(*Order of the Phoenix*, Chapter Six)</sup>

> Sirius, who was right beside Harry, let out his usual barklike laugh.
>
> “No one would have made me a prefect, I spent too much time in detention with James. Lupin was the good boy, he got the badge.”
>
> <sup>(*Order of the Phoenix*, Chapter Nine)</sup>

> Snape’s wand flew twelve feet into the air and fell with a little thud in the grass behind him. Sirius let out a bark of laughter.
>
> <sup>(*Order of the Phoenix*, Chapter Twenty-Eight)</sup>

This feature is somewhat unique to Sirius; throughout the whole series there is only one other instance of a laugh
being described as bark-like:

> Dudley gave a harsh bark of laughter then adopted a high-pitched, whimpering voice. “‘Don’t kill Cedric! Don’t kill Cedric!’ Who’s Cedric — your boyfriend?”
>
> <sup>(*Order of the Phoenix*, Chapter Twenty-Eight)</sup>

Thus, when imagining Sirius laughing, Harry rightly associated it with a barking sound.